# jquery expandable menu push body down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an expandable menu in mobile view that pushes the body of the page down using JQuery so the menu sits on top of the body without overlapping. I'm pretty sure I'm using the right commands but can't seem to pinpoint which elements to target.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button.navbar-toggle").click(function() {
  $("#myNavbar" ).toggleClass("open");
});
  });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
div.open{
  margin-bottom:120px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">#</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse open" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Any advice would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what your looking for is this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button.navbar-toggle").click(function() {
    $("#myNavbar" ).slideToggle();
    $('.homepage-wrapper').toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

make sure you have included the required jquery and bootstrap files

css

```
.homepage-wrapper {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.homepage-wrapper.open{
  margin-top:260px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Did a copy/paste and the menu still overlaps the body. Bootstrap file being used is: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js Jquery: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: ahh kk see updated answer, added the js and css you need :)

Comment: Thanks! I must not be following your instructions correctly. Think I figured it out though. I added .open to the <body>, removed the .navbar-fixed-top from the <nav> and that seemed to do it. Looks like you can't have the best of both worlds.

Comment: yeah the common approach would be to have the margin on the top of the `.homepage-wrapper` then have the navbar drop down over the top. Margin at the top is required as the fixed element takes up the space at the top of the browser.

Comment: No worries bud happy to help :)